# AngularJS : What to do when I need to apply 2 directives with Isolate scope on the same <input/> element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a form that collects information for a physical and mailing address. I have 2 directives that I have designed which work individually. The first is for looking up zip codes and automatically setting the city and state. The second directive sets the mailing address to the physical address when a check box is set ("Same as physical address").

The problem is that both of these custom directives use Isolate scope and when I use them together I get a "Multiple Directive Resource Contention" error which appears to be a result of 1 element w/2 directives that have isolate scope.

How should I restructure this? **The goal is to place this logic in a directive (or something else) that allows me to easily reuse this logic in multiple places** (i.e. not in individual controllers)

Here is my code http://plnkr.co/edit/stwdRS?p=preview

If you remove the ***same*** directive on the physicalZip input you'll notices that it works.

```
<label>Physical Zip</label> 
<input ng-model="physicalZip" same="mailZip" same-if="addressSame" zip-city-state="physicalZip" city='physicalCity' state='physicalState' /><br/>
```

Here are the directives

```
app.directive('zipCityState', function () {
return {
        scope: { zipCityState:'=', city: '=', state:'=' },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            // see plnkr for logic
        }
    };
});

app.directive('same', function () {
     return {
        scope: { same: '=', ngModel: '=', sameIf: '=' },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            // see plnkr for logic
        }
     };
 });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

The simple answer is that you can't. There is no way to apply two isolate scopes to one element, so your solution is to remove the one you need less.

## My Solution

To be perfectly honest with you, I don't really understand what your `zipCityState` directive is for, but it does seem to be the directive that you actually need. The `same` one is needlessly complicating things, so I have made substantial changes to your plunkr to eliminate it. I have replaced it with a flag that changes what is returned when you ask for the mailing address model.

I have outlined the details of my solution below. You can see it in action here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AJswigWyMHvBbBNvUUse?p=preview

### Controller

Here is my new controller. It uses an Angular 1.3 getter/setter property for `addressSame` and conditionally returns a different address object from `mailingAddress` depending on whether or not that value is true or false.

```
app.controller('addressController', function($scope){
  var Address = function() {
    this.address = '';
    this.zip = '';
    this.state = '';
    this.city = '';
  };

  addressSame = true;
  $scope.addressSame = function(value) {
    if(angular.isDefined(value))
      return addressSame = value;
    else
      return addressSame;
  };
  $scope.physicalAddress = new Address();

  mailingAddress = new Address();
  $scope.mailingAddress = function() {
    return addressSame ? $scope.physicalAddress : mailingAddress;
  };
});
```

### Directive

I removed the `same` directive, as there was no further use for it, and left the `zipCityState` intact, except for two lines of code that I changed for convention's sake (there is no change in logic).

### Template

The template no longer makes reference to the non-existent `same` directive, and instead makes use of the new property mechanics for `addressSame` and the new `mailingAddress` scope function.

```
<h3>Physical Address</h3>
<label>Physical Address</label> <input ng-model="physicalAddress.address" /><br/>
<label>Physical Zip</label> <input ng-model="physicalAddress.zip"
  zip-city-state="physicalAddress.zip" city='physicalAddress.city' state='physicalAddress.state' /><br/>
<label>Physical State</label> <input ng-model="physicalAddress.state" /><br/>
<label>Physical City</label> <input ng-model="physicalAddress.city" /><br/>

<h3>Mailing Address</h3>
<label>Same as Physical Address <input type="checkbox" ng-model="addressSame" ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}"/></label><br/>
<fieldset ng-disabled="addressSame()">
  <label>Mail Address</label> <input ng-model="mailingAddress().address" /><br/>
  <label>Mail Zip</label> <input ng-model="mailingAddress().zip" zip-city-state="mailingAddress().state" city='mailingAddress().city' state='mailingAddress().state'/><br/>
  <label>Mail State</label> <input ng-model="mailingAddress().state" /><br/>
  <label>Mail City</label> <input ng-model="mailingAddress().city" /><br/>
</fieldset>
```

### Admission

It is entirely possible that I broke the `zipCityState` directive, since I didn't know what to test for. I don't believe any changes I made should have broken it though.

Comment: This certainly could work. But I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to keep the logic out of the controller so that it can be reused across multiple views. The zipCityState directive sends the zip to an API and returns City and State to populate the form. So, the user types the zip and it automatically populates the city and state.

Comment: Wanting to reuse code is an admirable and understandable goal, but don't lose sight of the real objectives: readability and maintainability. Reusing design patterns is not the same as code duplication. If what you want to do elsewhere in the application is *exactly the same*, however, I would be putting all of this in one directive, and making my controller the controller *for that directive*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be easier to control the source of address on the checkbox action itself instead of tagging it on the source fields.

```
<h3>Physical Address</h3>
<label>Physical Address</label> <input ng-model="phyiscal.address" /><br/>

<label>Physical Zip</label> <input ng-model="physical.zip" zip-city-state="physical.zip" city='physical.city' state='physical.state' /><br/>

<label>Physical State</label> <input ng-model="physical.state" /><br/>
<label>Physical City</label> <input ng-model="physical.city" /><br/>


<h3>Mailing Address</h3>
<label>Same as Physical Address <input type="checkbox" ng-model="addressSame" ng-click="!!addressSame && copyAddress(physical, mail)" /></label><br/>
<label>Mail Address</label> <input ng-model="mail.address" /><br/>
<label>Mail Zip</label> <input ng-model="mail.zip" zip-city-state="mail.zip" city='mail.city' state='mail.state'/><br/>
<label>Mail State</label> <input ng-model="mail.state" /><br/>
<label>Mail City</label> <input ng-model="mail.city" /><br/>

$scope.copyAddress = function(source, destination) {
    destination = angular.copy(source);
}
```

Actually the "Physical" and the "Mail" part is a great candidate of directive too.

```
<h3>Physical Address</h3>
<address-block address="physical" name="Physical"></address-block>

<h3>Mailing Address</h3>
<label>Same as Physical Address <input type="checkbox" ng-model="addressSame" ng-click="!!addressSame && copyAddress(physical, mail)" /></label><br/>
<address-block address="mail" name="Mail"></address-block>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple isolate scopes on the same element.

But you don't necessarily need an isolate scope. All you need, it seems, is to be able to do two-way binding (and in some cases you can do away with one-way binding).

For that you need the `$parse` service. `$parse` evaluates the expression given to it, and can give you a function to assign value back. Suppose I am using your `same` directive as an illustration:

```
<input ng-model="obj.txt1" same="obj.p1" same-if="abc && xyz">
```

Before we continue, I suggest we use `require: "ngModel"` (but if you aren't assigning value to it, that's fine and you could get its expression exactly like `same` and `same-if`):

```
.directive("same", function($parse){
  return {
    require: ["ngModel"], // could be optional "?ngModel"
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
      var ngModel = ctrls[0];

      var sameGetFn   = $parse(attrs.same),
          sameIfGetFn = $parse(attrs.sameIf),
          sameSetFn   = sameGetFn.assign || angular.noop;

      // executes anytime `ngModel` is changed from the View-side, like ng-change
      ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
            // get the value of expression of "same-if"
        if (sameIfGetFn(scope)){
          // assign to expression of "same"
          sameSetFn(scope, ngModel.$modelValue);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Clearly, it's not doing exactly what you have in the plunker, but I think this example illustrates the approach you could take.

For example, if you need to watch for changes to the `same` expression from the model, you can do so as follows:

```
scope.$watch(function(){
  return sameGetFn(scope);
}, function(newValue, oldValue){
  // etc..
});
```

Related resources:

- `ngModelController`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController
- `$parse`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse